# Java swagger with JaxRS throwing errors

Tags: java, maven, jersey, swagger

I followed the guide found here:
https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Java-JAXRS-Quickstart

Here is my POM:

```
<!--  SWAGGER -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The Annotations are found fine, so i am assuming the POM is working OK

**For WEB.xml,** I tried doing multiple things, following the guide:

```
 <servlet>
            <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>com.thomsonreuters.ips.service;com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

<!-- SWAGGER serverlet? -->
<servlet>
          <servlet-name>JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
          <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>http://localhost:8080/{PROJECTNAME}</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
```

but this throws a wild error when i try to reach:

localhost:8080/{PROJECTNAME}/service/api-docs

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation.authorizations()Ljava/lang/String;
```

next I saw around the googleverse to modify the web.xml to the following:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
        </servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>2.0</param-value>
          </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.thomsonreuters.ips.service;com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs;</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

note the api.version and the new jaxrs init param.

when that happens, and i go to

```
http://localhost:8080/ScholarlyItemService/service/api-docs
```

i get no errors, but i do get useless webpage:

```
{"apiVersion":"0.0","swaggerVersion":"1.2"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost have it. What you see is not a useless webpage, it's rather the documentation of your service built by swagger as a json document. You have to annotate your code as shown in the Quickstart guide. This should show up in this document.

What you may actually want is the Swagger UI: http://swagger.wordnik.com/ to see this document in a readable way.

It took me a moment, but I got it running. You have to download from here: https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui, and copy the contents from the dist folder to your /webapp folder. You can then open the contained index.html in a browser. In my case, I could not access this document directly, so I had to put the dist' contents in a subfolder (e.g. /docs) and exclude this from my servlet mapping in web.xml as described here: http://blog.ericdaugherty.com/2010/02/excluding-content-from-url-pattern-in.html.

In the index.html change the url: "http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api/api-docs",
part to your api endpoint `http://localhost:8080/ScholarlyItemService/service/api-docs` and you will get your api documentation when calling `http://localhost:8080/ScholarlyItemService/docs/index.html`