# Unable to link Swagger-ui to my swagger Spring mvc project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm currently creating an API Rest using Eclipse, Spring Framework MVC, and I just added to my project swagger. I can access the json result of swagger but I need to add swagger ui.

Here are all my files creating for swagger-springmvc:

WebAppInitializer.java

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = null;

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {

        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "web");

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(SpringBaseWebConfiguration.class,
                SpringSwaggerConfiguration.class);

        // Manages the lifecycle
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
        sc.addListener(new ContextCleanupListener());

        // Spring WebMVC
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic springWebMvc = sc.addServlet("ws",
                new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        springWebMvc.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        springWebMvc.addMapping("/ws/*");
        springWebMvc.setAsyncSupported(true);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    protected final void cleanup() {
        if (ctx != null) {
            ctx.close();
        }
    }
}
```

SpringSwaggerConfiguration.java

```
public class SpringSwaggerConfiguration {
    public static final List<String> DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERNS = Arrays
            .asList(new String[]{"/com/sa/rnd/dark/resources/.*"});
    public static final String SWAGGER_GROUP = "ApiDark";
    public static final String RELATIVE_GROUP = "ApiDark";
    @Autowired
    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

/**
 * Adds the jackson scala module to the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
 * registered with spring Swagger core models are scala so we need to be
 * able to convert to JSON Also registers some custom serializers needed to
 * transform swagger models to swagger-ui required json format
 */
@Bean
public JacksonScalaSupport jacksonScalaSupport() {
    final JacksonScalaSupport jacksonScalaSupport = new JacksonScalaSupport();
    // Set to false to disable
    jacksonScalaSupport.setRegisterScalaModule(true);
    return jacksonScalaSupport;
}

/**
 * Global swagger settings
 */
@Bean
public SwaggerGlobalSettings swaggerGlobalSettings() {
    final SwaggerGlobalSettings swaggerGlobalSettings = new SwaggerGlobalSettings();
    swaggerGlobalSettings.setGlobalResponseMessages(springSwaggerConfig
            .defaultResponseMessages());
    swaggerGlobalSettings.setIgnorableParameterTypes(springSwaggerConfig
            .defaultIgnorableParameterTypes());
    return swaggerGlobalSettings;
}

/**
 * API Info as it appears on the swagger-ui page
 */
private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfo(
            "Swagger Spring MVC for Dark Api",
            "Sample application demonstrating how to use swagger-springmvc in a no-XML environment.",
            "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_service",
            "michael@laccetti.com", "Apache 2.0",
            "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html");
}

/**
 * Configure a SwaggerApiResourceListing for each swagger instance within
 * your app. e.g. 1. private 2. external apis Required to be a spring bean
 * as spring will call the postConstruct method to bootstrap swagger
 * scanning.
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public SwaggerApiResourceListing swaggerApiResourceListing() {
    // The group name is important and should match the group set on
    // ApiListingReferenceScanner
    // Note that swaggerCache() is by DefaultSwaggerController to serve the
    // swagger json
    final SwaggerApiResourceListing swaggerApiResourceListing = new SwaggerApiResourceListing(
            springSwaggerConfig.swaggerCache(), SWAGGER_GROUP);

    // Set the required swagger settings
    swaggerApiResourceListing
            .setSwaggerGlobalSettings(swaggerGlobalSettings());

    // Supply the API Info as it should appear on swagger-ui web page
    swaggerApiResourceListing.setApiInfo(apiInfo());

    // Use the default path provider
    swaggerApiResourceListing.setSwaggerPathProvider(springSwaggerConfig
            .defaultSwaggerPathProvider());

    // Global authorization - see the swagger documentation
    swaggerApiResourceListing.setAuthorizationTypes(authorizationTypes());

    // Sets up an auth context - i.e. which controller request paths to
    // apply global auth to
    swaggerApiResourceListing
            .setAuthorizationContext(authorizationContext());

    // Every SwaggerApiResourceListing needs an ApiListingReferenceScanner
    // to scan the spring request mappings
    swaggerApiResourceListing
            .setApiListingReferenceScanner(apiListingReferenceScanner());
    return swaggerApiResourceListing;
}

@Bean
/**
 * The ApiListingReferenceScanner does most of the work.
 * Scans the appropriate spring RequestMappingHandlerMappings
 * Applies the correct absolute paths to the generated swagger resources
 */
public ApiListingReferenceScanner apiListingReferenceScanner() {
    ApiListingReferenceScanner apiListingReferenceScanner = new ApiListingReferenceScanner();

    // Picks up all of the registered spring RequestMappingHandlerMappings
    // for
    // scanning
    apiListingReferenceScanner
            .setRequestMappingHandlerMapping(springSwaggerConfig
                    .swaggerRequestMappingHandlerMappings());

    // Excludes any controllers with the supplied annotations
    apiListingReferenceScanner.setExcludeAnnotations(springSwaggerConfig
            .defaultExcludeAnnotations());

    //
    apiListingReferenceScanner
            .setResourceGroupingStrategy(springSwaggerConfig
                    .defaultResourceGroupingStrategy());

    // Path provider used to generate the appropriate uri's
    apiListingReferenceScanner
            .setSwaggerPathProvider(relativeSwaggerPathProvider());

    // Must match the swagger group set on the SwaggerApiResourceListing
    apiListingReferenceScanner.setSwaggerGroup(SWAGGER_GROUP);

    // Only include paths that match the supplied regular expressions
    apiListingReferenceScanner.setIncludePatterns(DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERNS);

    return apiListingReferenceScanner;
}

private List<AuthorizationType> authorizationTypes() {
    final List<AuthorizationType> authorizationTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    authorizationTypes.add(new BasicAuth());
    return authorizationTypes;
}

@Bean
public AuthorizationContext authorizationContext() {
    final List<Authorization> authorizations = newArrayList();

    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope(
            "global", "accessEverything");

    AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[]{authorizationScope};
    authorizations.add(new Authorization("basic", authorizationScopes));

    AuthorizationContext authorizationContext = new AuthorizationContext.AuthorizationContextBuilder(
            authorizations).withIncludePatterns(DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERNS)
            .build();

    return authorizationContext;
}

// Relative path example
@Bean
public SwaggerApiResourceListing relativeSwaggerApiResourceListing() {
    SwaggerApiResourceListing swaggerApiResourceListing = new SwaggerApiResourceListing(
            springSwaggerConfig.swaggerCache(), RELATIVE_GROUP);
    swaggerApiResourceListing
            .setSwaggerGlobalSettings(swaggerGlobalSettings());
    swaggerApiResourceListing
            .setSwaggerPathProvider(relativeSwaggerPathProvider());
    swaggerApiResourceListing
            .setApiListingReferenceScanner(relativeApiListingReferenceScanner());
    return swaggerApiResourceListing;
}

@Bean
public ApiListingReferenceScanner relativeApiListingReferenceScanner() {

    ApiListingReferenceScanner apiListingReferenceScanner = 
            new ApiListingReferenceScanner();

    apiListingReferenceScanner
            .setRequestMappingHandlerMapping(springSwaggerConfig
                    .swaggerRequestMappingHandlerMappings());

    apiListingReferenceScanner.setExcludeAnnotations(springSwaggerConfig
            .defaultExcludeAnnotations());

    apiListingReferenceScanner
            .setResourceGroupingStrategy(springSwaggerConfig
                    .defaultResourceGroupingStrategy());

    apiListingReferenceScanner
            .setSwaggerPathProvider(relativeSwaggerPathProvider());

    apiListingReferenceScanner.setSwaggerGroup(RELATIVE_GROUP);
    apiListingReferenceScanner.setIncludePatterns(DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERNS);
    return apiListingReferenceScanner;
}

@Bean
public SwaggerPathProvider relativeSwaggerPathProvider() {
    return new ApiRelativeSwaggerPathProvider();
}

private class ApiRelativeSwaggerPathProvider extends
        DefaultSwaggerPathProvider {
    @Override
    public String getAppBasePath() {
        return "/ApiDark/ws";
    }
}
```

}

SpringBaseWebConfiguration.java :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sa.rnd.dark.resources",
        "com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration",
        "com.mangofactory.swagger.controllers"})

@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringBaseWebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/api-docs").setViewName("redirect:index.html");
    }

    /**
     * The message converters for the content types we support.
     *
     * @return the message converters; returns the same list on subsequent calls
     */
    private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getMessageConverters() {
        if (messageConverters == null) {
            messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();

            final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
            mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT);
            mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS,
                    false);
            mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,
                    false);
            mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
            messageConverters.add(mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter);
        }
        return messageConverters;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.addAll(getMessageConverters());
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer swaggerProperties() {
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer swaggerProperties = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        swaggerProperties.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(
                "swagger.properties"));
        return swaggerProperties;
    }
}
```

Here are my 3 files to add swagger to my project, atm I just decide to check just 1 method which is :

```
@Api(description = "CRUD services for containers working with WebDark",
        value = "CRUD Services Containers")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/container", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ContainersResources {
    /**
     * Find all children of a container.
     *
     * @param containerId
     *            ID of the parent container
     * @return ApiResponse
     */


    @ApiOperation(response = ApiResponse.class,
            value = "Find all children containers of one container",
            notes = "Find all children containers of one container")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{containerId}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody ApiResponse<List<ContainerModel>> getContainerChildren(
            @ApiParam(required = true, value = "The id of the container parent",
                    name = "containerId")@PathVariable("containerId") final String containerId) {
        ApiResponse<List<ContainerModel>> result = new ApiResponse<>();
        result.setMessage("getContainerChildren  method of new Api Dark");
        result.setSuccess(true);
        result.setTotal(9000);
        return result;
    }
}
```

My results : I can access the following url `http://localhost:8080/ApiDark/ws/api-docs` but I get the json value like :

> {"apiVersion":"1","swaggerVersion":"1.2","authorizations":{"basicAuth":{"type":"basicAuth"}},"info":{"title":"Swagger Spring MVC for Dark Api","description":"Sample application demonstrating how to use swagger-springmvc in a no-XML environment.","termsOfServiceUrl":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_service","contact":"michael@laccetti.com","license":"Apache 2.0","licenseUrl":"http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"}}

That's why I decided to add swagger-ui. I add the content of dist folder (taken from [swagger-ui](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui)) to my src/main/webapp folder. And modify the content of index.html to point to my url :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/ApiDark/ws/api-docs.json",
  dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
```

But I can't access to swagger-ui interface, I just have the json result... Need help to make it work please !

Comment: you have your answer well explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807791/integrating-swagger-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 3):

This issue seems old but just to share, with the recent version of swagger-springmvc and springmvc-ui, it has become very easy and less complicated to integrate swagger & swagger-ui with your web service to see in production REST api documentation.

@EnableSwagger annotation is added that enables swagger-springmvc out of the box. The generated swagger json Resource Listing can be accessed at /api-docs.

You may refer to following link for the steps on integrating swagger-springmvc and swagger-ui with your spring mvc project.
https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc

Comment: Even though I am using @EnableSwagger, I am seeing the same issue.

Comment: please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807791/integrating-swagger-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'I can't access to swagger-ui interface'?

In my case, my browser did not load the index.html (I think it throw 404), which I had in a subfolder together with all the dist files: webapp/doc/index.html. I had to exclude the subfolder from the servlet mapping in web.xml as I shortly described here:
[Java swagger with JaxRS throwing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231197/java-swagger-with-jaxrs-throwing-errors/23474929#23474929)

My web.xml snippet looks like this finally:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>My application servlet-name</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/doc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

(why this works see here:http://blog.ericdaugherty.com/2010/02/excluding-content-from-url-pattern-in.html)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I found a work-around by redirecting the web.xml to the swagger index.html ;)