# Swagger for Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger

Regarding integrating Swagger in Spring MVC:

Swagger is not displaying the `GET/PUT/POST` documentation for `@RequestMapping`

In my Spring MVC Rest webservice application, I have a Login controller and a Student Controller.
I just configured Swagger to generate the Rest API documentation. 
Reference: http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-configure-swagger-generate

**Question**: However, Swagger is displaying only the class-level path, and I guess its not wven displaying the class level `@RequestMapping`. , **The method level mappings are ignored. Any reason why** ?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public class LoginController {


@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/students/")
public class StudentController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "{departmentID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public MyResult getStudents(@PathVariable String departmentID) {
      // code
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "student", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public MyResult getStudentInfo(
        @RequestParam(value = "studentID") String studentID,
        @RequestParam(value = "studentName") String studentName) {
     //code
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "student", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity<Student> updateStudentInfo(@RequestBody Student student) {
       //code
  }
```

Swagger Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    private SpringSwaggerConfig swaggerConfig;

    @Autowired
    public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig swaggerConfig) {
        this.swaggerConfig = swaggerConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    // Don't forget the @Bean annotation
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation() {
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.swaggerConfig).apiInfo(
                apiInfo()).includePatterns("/.*");
    }

private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo("my API", "API for my app", "", "contact@localhost.com", "License type",
                "something like a License URL");
        return apiInfo;
    }
```

Output:

```
http://localhost:8080/studentapplication/api-docs

{
apiVersion: "1.0",
swaggerVersion: "1.2",
apis: [
{
path: "/default/login-controller",
description: "Login Controller"
},
{
path: "/default/student-controller",
description: "Student Controller"
}
],
info: {
title: "Student API",
description: "API for Student",
termsOfServiceUrl: "StudentApp API terms of service",
contact: "abc@xyz.com",
license: "sometext",
licenseUrl: "License URL"
}
}
```

**Update:**

you also need the below config in the spring config XML file, as mentioned in https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc

```
    <!-- to enable the default documentation controller-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mangofactory.swagger.controllers"/>

    <!-- to pick up the bundled spring configuration-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration"/>

    <!-- Direct static mappings -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="*.html" location="/, classpath:/swagger-ui"/>

    <!-- Serve static content-->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Comment: Check the output of http://localhost:8080/studentapplication/api-docs/default/login-controller and http://localhost:8080/studentapplication/api-docs//default/student-controller

Comment: Okay. I don't know how much the swagger-springmvc's developers look in SO, so if you don't get a reply in a timely manner, I'd suggest to just open on issue on their repository.

Comment: Appreciate that suggestion, @webron , thank you

Comment: @webron I fixed the issue, and posted as answer

Comment: @spiderman How to config these if i use the annotaion method without having a spring config XML?

Comment: @xi.lin Sorry, I haven't tried that

Comment: Newer Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333853/410439

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever output seeing now is good, we won't see the swagger UI and the `GET/POST/PUT` method level mappings here in this `JSON` output. So that's fine. It shows only the class level path.

To see the actual Swagger UI with the `GET/POST/PUT` method level mappings, and the URL's, we need 
to download the `SwaggerUI` which is available here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

And then navigate to this `index.html` file: `swagger-ui-master\swagger-ui-master\dist\index.html`
here, edit the source JSON URL to your application api-docs URL :

ie:

```
  $(function () {
      window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
      url: "studentapplication/api-docs",
      dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
      supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'],
```

Now you see everything!!!

I was just one step away...