# Swagger REST API documentation with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger

I want to use Swagger 2.0 with my Spring Boot RESTful web service to generate documentation.  I have searched quite a bit for an answer to this.  Basically I have a Spring Boot project with a set of controllers and I want to document the API's.  I have the following dependencies setup in my POM file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my Swagger configuration class with the @Configuration and @EnableSwagger2:

```
      @Configuration
      @EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/.*"))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("My application title")
            .description("This is a test of documenting EST API's")
            .version("V1.2")
            .termsOfServiceUrl("http://terms-of-services.url")
            .license("LICENSE")
            .licenseUrl("http://url-to-license.com")
            .build();
    }

}
```

From what I have gathered in reading a couple of other answers here that at this point I should be able to see something at a URL such as http://myapp/v2/api-docs or alternatively http://localhost:8080/myapp/api-docs  I have made the assumption that the "myapp" portion of the above URL refers to the name of the class in which my main resides (is this correct)?  Also I have tried this with port 8080 and port 80 and the bottom line is that I see nothing other than site can't be reached.  I have looked at the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720090/a-simple-way-to-implement-swagger-in-a-spring-mvc-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807791/swagger-for-spring-mvc-project) however I'm not having any success.  Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this: http://localhost:8080/myapp/swagger-ui.html

Comment: Simple configuration - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64333853/410439

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the following documentation :
https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#springfox-swagger-ui

The endpoint is now on swagger-ui.html, for your case, it will be http://localhost:8080/myapp/swagger-ui.html

Comment: Thank you, an additional question, the "myapp" portion of the URL is this the name of the class in which my "main" resides?

Comment: I'm not even seeing the port 8080 being used when looking at netstat.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452072/how-do-i-choose-the-url-for-my-spring-boot-webapp

Answer (score 0):

I used, `<artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>` with

```
public class OpenApiConfiguration{

     @Bean
     public GroupedOpenApi abcApp(){
        String[] abcAppRootPath={"com.stockoverflow.swagger"};
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("my app").packagesToScan(abcAppRootPath).build();
    }
}
```

reference : https://springdoc.org/#getting-started

Answer (score 0):

```
1- Use this url to access swagger documentation- 
   http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
   http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
2- To view OpenAPI description-
   http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs
```

Here you can find integration example with sample source code- 
https://javadrill.com/spring-boot-3-swagger-integration-example

Answer (score 0):

Since the required dependencies are already being used in the `pom.xml` file, here is the implementation that can be used for Swagger 2 in the spring boot project for all the rest-controller classes.

```java
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration;
import springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfigurationBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry
                .addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath://META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    UiConfiguration uiConfiguration() {
        return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder()
                .defaultModelExpandDepth(-1)
                .build();
    }
}
```

The following config file can be modified and used as per needs especially in the `uiConfiguration()` method. The rest-controller wherever is needed can be annotated with `@Api` on the class and `@ApiOperation` on the method of interest such as either a `post/get` call. Feel free to explore.